# Feasibility Question : Salesforce as pure backend solution for a mobile app

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, database.com

Is it possible to develop an iOS app (with Swift/Obj C/XCode as front end tools) and Salesforce (Database.com) as backend ?

The communication between the app and Database.com to be done only on REST calls.

Has anyone used such a setup ?

Comment: Immediate thought is the number of API calls could be the limiting factor

Comment: Composite API might help you manage governors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use salesforce backend for Android as well. You need to use Mobile SDK of Salesoforce to build to those applications. Please check this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forceios). As @Eric pointed out if you are using REST API's then you've got some governor limits which needs to taken care of. Here is one more link for developing native iOS app. [Getting Started in Mobile Development with iOS using Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/ru/mobile/getting-started/ios)
Hope I answered your question

Comment: Absolutely is possible, as @rohit-mourya says.
It should be noted that there are many different approaches and flavours of apps available (inc Native, Hybrid Local, Hybrid Remote) and each has their own set of features and pros and cons.
At [MobileCaddy](https://www.mobilecaddy.net) we use Hybrid Remote approach which makes use of a combination of call types to hugely reduce the impact on API Call limits. I'd be very happy to share more info on this how and how make full offline apps a breeze.